# PDO - Mapping placeholders to a merged array

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is from phpDelusions.net:

> "In case there are other placeholders in the query, you could use `array_merge()` function to join all the variables into a single array, adding your other variables in the form of arrays, in the order they appear in your query:"

```
$arr = [1,2,3];
$in  = str_repeat('?,', count($arr) - 1) . '?';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE foo=? AND column IN ($in) AND bar=? AND baz=?";
$stm = $db->prepare($sql);
$params = array_merge([$foo], $arr, [$bar, $baz]);
$stm->execute($params);
$data = $stm->fetchAll();
```

How do the placeholders in the query map to the merged `$params` array? Are the names `foo`, `bar`, `baz` used as key of the `$params` array and this gets mapped to the placeholders?

Comment: What are you expecting? Can you give a input/output.

Answer (score 0):

No. `$params` will have numerical keys. From [the manual](https://php.net/array_merge) (emphasis mine):

> If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one. ***If, however, the arrays contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended.***

Your arguments for `array_merge()` do not have string keys:

```
$params = array_merge(
    [$foo],       // [0 => $foo]
    $arr,         // [0 => 1, 1 => 2, 2 => 3]
    [$bar, $baz]  // [0 => $bar, 1 => $baz]
);
```

Since these are numerical keys, the values will be appended and `$params` will essentially end up looking like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => $foo
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => $bar
    [5] => $baz
];
```

These values will be passed into the placeholders in your query in that order, so if you move the conditions of your query around you also need to change your `array_merge()` to make sure the values are in the same order.

For example, if you move the `bar=?` condition and change your query to be:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE foo=? AND bar=? AND column IN ($in) AND baz=?
```

Then you'll have to move the `$bar` value as well and change your `array_merge()` to be:

```
$params = array_merge([$foo, $bar], $arr, [$baz]);
```